# Prove inequality of two graphs (Single-crossing property)

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that for $x\in [\frac23, 1]$, $y_1<y_2$, where
$y_1=\frac19+\frac{x}8+\frac5{162x}$ and $y_2=\frac{1+x}2-\frac89\sqrt{\frac23 x}$.

When I plot the two graphs, its clear, but can I prove it mathematically?

I managed to solve it! First, it's easy to prove that when $x=\frac23$, $y_2=y_1$. Then, I set $F=y_2-y_1$. Then I derive $\frac{dF}{dx} = K/x^2$ whereby $K=\frac78N^2+\frac5{162}-\frac49\sqrt{\frac23}\sqrt{N}^3.$ I then show that $K>0$ for $2/3<x<1$ by showing that $K|_{x=2/3}>0$ and $\frac{dK}{dx}>0$ for all $2/3<x<1$. Since $K>0$, $y_2>y_1$ for $2/3<x<1$.

Comment: Is my edit correct?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Consider

$$y=y_2-y_1\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$$

$$\implies y'\ge0(\text{non decreasing})$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\eqalign{
  & {1 \over 9} + \left( {{1 \over 8} + {5 \over {162}}} \right)x < {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}x - {8 \over 9}\sqrt {{2 \over 3}} \sqrt x   \cr 
  & {8 \over 9}\sqrt {{2 \over 3}} \sqrt x  < {1 \over 2} - {1 \over 9} + \left( {{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 8} - {5 \over {162}}} \right)x  \cr 
  & {8 \over 9}\sqrt {{2 \over 3}} \sqrt x  < {7 \over {18}} + {{223} \over {648}}x  \cr 
  & 576\sqrt {{2 \over 3}} \sqrt x  < 252 + 223x  \cr 
  & 0 < 223\left( {\sqrt x } \right)^{\,2}  - 576\sqrt {{2 \over 3}} \sqrt x  + 252 \cr} 
$$

The last is the equation of a parabola (in $\sqrt{x}$), with vertical axis, directed upwards, which at $\sqrt{x}=0$ has a positive value of $252$ and the discriminant $$
\Delta ^{\,2}  = 576^{\,2} {2 \over 3} - 4 \cdot 223 \cdot 252 =  - 3600 < 0
$$
is negative.

So the inequality is true, for all non-negative $x$.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but the equation was mis-typed. y1 should be y1=(1/9)+(x/8)+(5/(162x))